# Should pure java methods be static?

Tags: java

Lets say we have a pure java method. Its a simple validation method. It validates if the input is correct, and throws an exception if not.

```
    static void validateInputIsOk(String input) throws InvalidArgumentException {
        if (input == null || !input.equals("Valid input")) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(new String[]{"Bad input"});
        }
    }
```

Its pure, and its static, its small, and easy to reason about.

So i`ve been reading a lot about java static methods and a lot of people advises against this.
Mainly due to testability.
Now that part i fully get. Its not easy mocking a static method. If I use this validator inside some other unit, then I must either accept it will be a part of the test (which could be ok since its pure), or use some sort of static mock framework.

But in order to make it mockable, and non static, I would have to sacrifice the simplicity and readability of my code. I would have to deal with creating the object, and possibly passing it as a parameter to the unit using it.

So in this light I would favour making my pure methods static, and not bother mocking them. It seems the to keep my code most simple and clean.

Would you think im right? Is it something im missing here?

Comment: Lots of times with simple pure functions you don't need to mock them. If you're not going to need to mock it, I don't see why you should worry about it being static if that works for you.

Comment: This is probably nothing you can get _the correct and concise_ answer, so it does not fit well with SO. You mention you want to avoid object creation and have a more readable method. Well, just look where this method is visible... should it be exposed? Is validation logic an integral part of a business class, which should hide that kind of knowledge (information hiding principle)? In other words: why would client code, i.e. another class, first call the validate function, before calling another function?

Comment: I am predicting it will be closed as opinion-based. * *sigh* *. To me, it just doesn't feel like a Java style. I assume a typical Java developer would write a class `InputValidator` with an instance method `validate(String)` and pass it as a dependency to the places where it's going to be used.

Comment: well, this is a opinion-based question... so, imho, your method looks like the typical Util or Helper class. Even IDEs will raise a "warning" saying that your method should be static. However, not all these methods may be static, if they are not public... doing mocking is easier with instance methods, so... as I said, this is more an opinion-based question.

Comment: I also find `validateInputIsOk` to be a terrible method name. It suggests this class can be cluttered with stuff like `validateOutput`, `validateSomethingElseIsOk`, `validateInputIsNotOk`, etc, which will eventually make it an all-purpose dumpster for validation methods. (* *sigh* *, voted to reopen)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes I was kind of waiting for that reply.  it's not a real method, don't worry

Comment: @dd-developer I guess `validate` and `isOk` shouldn't come together

Comment: Here I am wondering if the method should just return a `boolean`. And once again I go once again down the rabbit hole of "Why is control flow and exception flow treated differently in most languages?"

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you only should mock methods that are public. I would also argue, that you only should test methods that are public. If your tests get too big this way, you should consider splitting up your implementation into more public classes, not necessarily make them non static.

Comment: Only mock methods that are public? I disagree entirely. Say you have a complex, private, static method. You absolutely do want to test this to avoid regressions. It seems like a very dangerous shortcut to say only public methods should be mocked (not to mention plain wrong)

Comment: Sounds like a good recipe for trouble :D

Comment: @ChrisNeve _"Say you have a complex, private, static method"_ - if it's complex it belongs to separate helper class IMO and should have own tests

Answer (score 1):

Methods that have no side-effects, the term is **functions**, should be static. And are *good* style. `Math` offers many such functions.

For testing, one would not mock these functions, but test them in isolation.

Comment: Could you expand what you mean by "side-effects"? Throwing an exception seems like a side-effect to me.

Comment: @Conner a good point; I meant: **No state.** (No internal state, no writing to the system.) I see a thrown exception more as a short-cut in the evaluation, and would call the code still adhering to _functional programming_. Just like division-by-zero.